# javascript:object

Tags: javascript

At last there i see a smell of closure in the following code.

```
function create(parent) {
var F = function() {};
 F.prototype = parent;
return new F();
}

var masterObject = {a: "masterObject value"}
var object1 = create(masterObject);
var object2 = create(masterObject);
var object3 = create(masterObject);
var object3.a = "overridden value";

object1.a; // "masterObject value"
object2.a; // "masterObject value"
object3.a; // "overridden value"

masterObject.a = "new masterObject value"//value is changed now

object1.a; // "new masterObject value"
object2.a; // "new masterObject value"
object3.a; // "overridden value"
```

the value of object1.a ,abject2.a is changed permamently .Is this because i made a change in global variable or that is the affect of closure?since i have not invoked the Create() function again why is the value changed automatically?
last question "when i made a change in global variable does that automatically affect all the object using tht variable?"in my view to make an effect of that variable i should call the Create() function again isn't it?

Comment: See http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access `object3.a`, JavaScript first looks at the object's properties. If the object doesn't have a property called `a`, the object's prototype is checked next.

Setting `object3.a = "overridden value";` gives `object3` a property called `a`. It doesn't affect your prototype's `a` property.

Since `object1` and `object2` don't have a property called `a`, but their prototype does, when you modify `masterObject`'s `a` property, the value changes globally for all objects that have `masterObject` as their prototype.

Even though you gave `object3` a property called `a`, but you can still access the prototype's `a` property, which remains the same:

```
object3.__proto__.a; // "new masterObject value"
```

Basically, by giving `object3` a property called `a`, you're putting the object's new property "in front" of the prototype's property.

Comment: last question "when i made a change in global  variable does that automatically affect all the object using tht variable?"in my view to make an effect of that variable i should call the Create() function again

Comment: @MaizerePathak: It's not really a global variable. It's a prototype. Your `create()` function assigns `masterObject` to be your object's prototype, so whatever you do to `masterObject` will affect all objects using it as their prototype.

Answer (score 0):

When you alter an object's 'a' property directly (as you do with `var object3.a = "overridden value";` (which shouldn't have a `var` in front of it), you alter that instance's own 'a' property.

So, what really happens is:

`object3.a = "overridden value";` here you **create** a new property on object3. It didn't have an 'a' property before. Its prototype did however, so `object3.a` was legal and would refer to the prototype's 'a' property.

`masterObject.a = "new masterObject value"` here you alter the **prototype** of all objects (created by `create()`). So if you access the property 'a' on objects, it will now be changed, except for those which have **their own** 'a' properties (such as object3).

Comment: Answering Maizere's question on the comment on Blender's answer: You don't have to change the `create()` function. Altering the prototype at any moment will directly alter all objects of that type, so to speak. Naturally, they will not be "altered", but they are bound to their prototype, and changes to it are affected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how inheritance works in [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based) languages, such as javascript. When you call `create(masterObject)`, you are returning a new instance of a function object (that you call `F`) with its prototype set to `masterObject`. That means that the prototype field for `object1`, `object2`, and `object3` point to the same object, `masterObject`.

The statement:

```
object3.a  = "overriden value"
```

creates a field called `a` in `object3` and assigns it the string `"overriden value"`, and thats what you get when you examine `object3.a`. But when you look at `object1.a`, the interpreter notices that the `a` field does not exist in `object1` so it follows the prototype link to its parent and examines that for a field called `a`. In this case, the prototype link points to `masterObject` which has a field called `a` that holds the string `"masterObject value"` and thats what you see. If `masterObject` did not have a field called `a`, the interpreter would follow the prototype link again and again until it finds an `a` field or until it reaches an object with an empty prototype link and it will then return the value `undefined`.

So by changing `masterObject.a`, you change what you see when you examine `object1.a` and `object2.a` because `object1` and `object2` do not have a field called `a`, so they "inherit" it from their parent, `masterObject`.

This does not happen when you examine `object3.a` because you created a field called `a` in `object3` that holds the string `"overridden value"`.

If, at the end of your code, you add:

```
delete object3.a;
```

you would now see `"new masterObject value"` when you look at `object3.a`, because `object3` no longer has a field called `a`, so it "inherits" it from its parent, `masterObject`.